# Card auto alignment

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, canvas

Im working on a card game in unity.. Where I am working on the alignment of cards which should look like an arc.

So for now I have achieved this by placing 8 empty gameObjects as max card number is 8 with a specific rotation and position.

And using this code down below to get the cards spawn:

```
int clicks = 0;
public List<GameObject> _playerHandPoints; //playerHandPoints is the 8 empty gameObject created in canvas and passed to this via inspector

GameObject card = Instantiate(cardModel, _playerHandPoints[clicks].transform.position, _playerHandPoints[clicks].transform.rotation);
clicks += 1;
```

**So in the above case as you can see I'm instantiating the cards with empty gameobjects position and rotation and incresing it to go to next point by click count. So, the cards come from left to right and spawn in the points one by one every time the draw button below the cards in the image is clicked**

Here I want the card to actually center align itself. For instance let me say i click the draw button and i get one card i want it to be place right above the draw button. And now lets say i clicked the draw button again 2 times. Which means I 3 cards. I want them to center align themselves accordingly. Like if i have 5 or 7 cards the cards placement should look like a proper semi circle like a chinese fan or like wrapped around the button equally. So to brief... Starts in between with 1 card as the count increases it need to center align itself properly like a chinese fan. I really gave a lot of thought and I'm so done. Not able to get an idea on what to do how to do anything. I feel like being stuck in a void... Any help or a tip will really be really appreciated thanks... And last thing i want all of this to be happening in canvas_UI

Answer (score 1):

looks like it can be solved by polar coordinates ... Divide the arc in the number of segment according to the Draw and then just place them at those coordinates.

```
x = radius * cos(theta)
y = radius * sin(theta)
z = constant;
```

if arc starts at 45 deg and ends at 135 deg ... then it is a 90 deg arc.

suppose you draw 2 cards ... then there will be 3 segments in the arc for your cards to be center aligned.

so points will be at 45 + 1 * (90/3) and 45 + 2 * (90/3) angles,

then just put this angles in the above polar equation.

Comment: Hey @vivek599. Thanks for the answer. At this point of time im not so good at unity... So i really dint understand what polar coordinates mean or how to do the arc in my the arc is manually set by me... Hope you can explain me that with any code example. Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system go through it.

Comment: Hey @vivek, Just wanna know `then just put this angles in the above polar equation.` which equation above are you stating here.

Comment: And @vivek. I'm trying to understand this.. So, ill tell you my own example and let me know if I'm heading right or wrong... So lets say my arc starts at 0deg and ends at 180 deg... which means i have a full 18deg arc... And then there are 8 segments as my maximum card is 8.. Now i draw 2 cards so the points should be at 0 + 1 * (180/8) & 0 + 2 * (180/8) angles? So is this right?

Comment: No, your arc angle will very with every draw and it will increase or decrease according to draw and play event. place gameobjects programmatically every draw. it should not be too heavy for your CPU to handle. if your maximum card is 8 and you want to position all of them then your calculation is correct. You only have to generate polar points according to how many cards you want to display. You can keep arc at fix angle and just vary the number of drawn cards and segments will generate accordingly. and Place those angel at THETA

Comment: I guess as you said. I want my cards to automatically align in center. like if i have 3 cards or 4 or 5. It should keep aligning itself in center. But the maximum cards that can be displayed is 8. Anyways vivek thank you so much... Ill learn about it understand it and try it out... Really thank you. :D